# Starting quick contact from a home screen shortcut?

Tags: android

On several phones like a Nexus or a HTC phone you can add a quick contact shortcut to the home screen.  When you press the persons image you get the little bouncy popup that has various icons in it.  I am trying to duplicate this behavior.

Here is some logging of the intent that is fired when the quick contact is launched from a shortcut:

```
02-01 06:55:58.460: INFO/ActivityManager(1259): Starting activity: Intent { act=com.android.contacts.action.QUICK_CONTACT dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/2795i4464ea058cf583f3/177 flg=0x14200000 cmp=com.motorola.blur.contacts/com.android.contacts.ui.QuickContactActivity bnds=[18,253][108,340] (has extras) }
```

I have tried to duplicate this without success:

```
final Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent("com.android.contacts.action.QUICK_CONTACT");
shortcutIntent.addFlags(0x14200000);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/2795i694f803d0e56adba/182");
shortcutIntent.setData(uri);

final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, contact.name);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON, contact.icon);
```

This makes a shortcut just fine and the logs are almost identical except for the [extras].  I have not figured out what the extras I need to be sending.

```
02-01 07:01:53.147: INFO/ActivityManager(1259): Starting activity: Intent { act=com.android.contacts.action.QUICK_CONTACT dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/2795i694f803d0e56adba/182 flg=0x14200000 cmp=com.motorola.blur.contacts/com.android.contacts.ui.QuickContactActivity bnds=[245,252][355,382] }

02-01 07:01:53.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12317): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-01 07:01:53.280: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(12317):     at com.android.contacts.ui.QuickContactActivity.onNewIntent(QuickContactActivity.java:77)
```

Does anyone know the correct way to call the quick contact from a shortcut or what the extras I need to send are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `intent.putExtra(ContactsContract.QuickContact.EXTRA_MODE, QuickContact.MODE_SMALL);`